# integration along fibres and kunneth

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

suppose $X\times I$ is a product of a smooth manifold and unit interval.
There is a map $pi_*:\Omega^k_{X\times I} \rightarrow \Omega^{k-1}_X$ called integration along fibres.

Similar operation exists on singular cochains. Do these operations correspond to Kunneth formula ?

Answer (score 1):

Künneth formula is given by the *pull back* maps: if $p$ and $q$ are the projections from $X\times Y$ to $X$ and $Y$, the map $(\alpha ,\beta )\mapsto p^*\alpha \wedge q^*\beta $ from $\Omega ^r_X\times \Omega ^s_Y$ to $\Omega ^{r+s}_{X\times Y}$
induces the map $H^r(X)\otimes H^s(Y)\rightarrow H^{r+s}(X\times Y)$ which appears in  the Künneth formula.

If $\pi :X\rightarrow Y$ is a proper submersion, with fibers of dimension $n$, integration along the fibers $\Omega ^{r+n}_X\rightarrow \Omega ^{r}_Y$ induces the *Gysin* map $H^{r+n}(X)\rightarrow H^r(Y)$.